# Can an armblade require double attunement if it integrates a magic weapon that normally requires attunement?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, unearthed-arcana, attunement

I'm pretty new to D&D, and right now I'm trying to make a character starting at a higher level for a campaign. The DM is allowing us to start with some magical items of our choice.

Using the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, I decided to make a Warforged. The Warforged race has a few exclusive magical items, one of which is the *armblade*.

The "Magic Armblades" sidebar (from the original version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, as it appears in [UA: Magic Items of Eberron](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_Magic_Items_of_Eberron.pdf#page=3)) says:

> An *armblade* isn’t inherently considered to be a magic weapon for purposes of overcoming damage resistance. However, any sort of magical melee weapon could be created as an *armblade*, so you could acquire a *vicious armblade* or a *vorpal armblade*.

However, as the *armblade* already requires attunement, if I make a magical weapon that already requires attunement as an *armblade*, does the resulting weapon require double attunement?

Comment: Note: the description of this magic item was changed in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* and in the updated version of *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*. I'm not sure if it changes the question/answers.

Comment: Here's the updated version of the question along with its answer, unfortunately I can't select the answer as correct for 2 days :(
[Can a magic item require attunement twice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163961/can-an-item-require-attunement-twice)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No, attunement is attunement

An item can either require attunement or not. The armblade requiring attunement simply means the weapon requires attunement (as in attaching it to yourself) even if the normal variant of the magical weapon doesn't.

Specifically for the "number of attunements", the restriction is on the *number* of magical items not the number of attunement, as per the DMG (p. 138):

> An item can be attuned to only one creature at a time and a creature can be attuned to no more than three magic items at a time.

Comment: So, just to clarify, you're saying that an Armblade made of a magic weapon would count as two magic items for the purposes of attunement cap?

Comment: @winterborne No, I'm saying it doesn't. As it is only one item (singular object), it counts as one.

Answer (score 4):

### No, you only attune once

> ..., any sort of magical melee weapon could be created as an armblade, so you could acquire a vicious armblade or a vorpal armblade.

The above phrase simply refers to the fact that an armblade can be enchanted in the same way as any other magical weapon.

That is, magical weapons in the Dungeon's Masters guide (and other sources) state the kinds of weapons that can hold a given type of enchantment.

For example, "Vicious Weapon" says "Weapon(any)". Meaning that potentially any kind of weapon could be found that has this type of magic: A vicious longsword, a vicious warhammer and so on.

So, what this is saying is that you could get a vicious armblade in the same way that you could get a vicious longsword. But even if the armblade always requires attunement anyway, this has no additional effect, since you are only limited by the number of items you can attune (not 'enchantments').